# show index of the image in the validation message in october cms

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, octobercms

I'm building a function to upload multiple images using OctoberCMS. The validation works fine. What I want is for, when we upload multiple images, if one image doesn't meet the validation rule, the error message will come like this.

[image: october cms validation error message]

Is it possible to change `progress_image.3` into `3rd image`. If so then the error message has to appear like this.

```
The 3rd image has invalid image dimensions.
```

I want to show the index of the image in the message. Any suggestions? ideas?

These are my validation rules.

```
protected $rules = [
    'progress_date' => 'required',
    'progress_image' => 'required',
    'progress_image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|dimensions:width=800,height=500|max:2048'
];
```

This is my relation.

```
public $attachMany = [
    'progress_image' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try `Validator::replacer`

> Plugin.php

```
// ...
use Validator;
use RainLab\Pages\Controllers\Index as PageController;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot() {

      Validator::replacer('required', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {

          // if attribute match with proper signature
          if(starts_with($attribute, 'progress_image.')) {
            $attributeArr = explode('.', $attribute);
            $newMessage = strtr($message, [$attribute => " image no. $attributeArr[1] "]);
            return $newMessage;
          }

          // otherwise return message as it is
          return $message;
      });

      // ...
```

** I just tested it with normal messages and it worked well, but  for your scenario I tried and do some parse and replace string but not able to test it on that kind of field, so may be you need to tweak it little bit.

reference : https://octobercms.com/docs/services/validation#custom-error-messages

> **Note** : It will run for all fields with required validator.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Awesome!! this is working. But is it possible to dynamically loop through the validation rules without specify each. `Validator::replacer('required')`

Comment: hmm may be you put foreach loop outer side to do so, I am not sure of any other good solution atm.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a third parameter to `$request->validate()` which allows you to override the validation messages to display thus allowing you to pass custom error messages:

```
$messages = [];

foreach ($this->progress_image as $key => $val) {
    $messages['progress_image.' . $key . '.dimensions'] = 'The ' . ($key + 1) . ' image has invalid dimensions.';
}
```

Then when you call `$request->validate()` be sure to pass the third parameter with `$messages`.

Comment: I'm using `validation` class a `traits`. In that how to place this code?